# ssis 2012 package fails from Master package in SQL agent, but runs well alone in SQL Agent

Tags: ssis-2012, sql-agent-job

I met one strange situation: there are one SSIS 2012 package, a child package. If I set up one schedule job run this package in SQL Agent, it works.

But, if I set up one schedule job for one master package to call this child package in SQL Agent, it failed. The error message is:

> There is no project to reference

The whole Message is as below:

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.5058.0 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  10:07:26  Error: 2015-07-29 10:07:27.83     Code: 0xC00220E6     Source: Exec Create Export File      Description: There is no project to reference.  End Error  Error: 2015-07-29 10:07:27.83     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Exec Create Export File      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  10:07:26  Finished: 10:07:27  Elapsed:  0.938 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

The schedule job's property is:

`Package source is File System.`

I have checked the Properties of this child package. But I didn't find anything wrong.

Comment: I want to supplement that the master package also calls other children packages. They are fine. Only the specific child package shows error. And those children packages have the same settings in Properties.

Comment: And if I run the master package in BIDS manually, it works fine. No error shows up for the specific child package.

Comment: The problem has been solved. The root cause is that there is one File Connection Manager, which has the same name as the child package. If I change the File Connection Manager to another name, and use it for Execute Package Task to call the child package, it works fine.